# Superfish module seems to "Ignore" it's very own library

Tags: theming, navigation

I have a problem connecting the Superfish library to the module... I've tried to Google this issue and the error I got, but found no direct solution. Here are more details:

I've installed the module alright but when I go to `admin/config/user-interface/superfish`, it asks me for the library path. I've tried many variations such as:

```
/public_html/sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries/Superfish
/public_html/sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries/
sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries/Superfish/
sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries/
public_html/sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries/Superfish
public_html/sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries
/public_html/sitesname.com/sites/all/libraries/Superfish/superfish.js
```

Nothing seems to work and I keep getting the (kinda wired) error **"File not found"**. Any ideas?

Comment: put the libraries in this path "sites\all\libraries\superfish\superfish.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sites/all/libraries/superfish with "superfish" all lower case might do the trick, if you have uppercase "Superfish" it will not work (at least on *nix).

Answer (score 1):

Download the Superfish library and extract it to sites/all/libraries/superfish (so that the superfish.js will be located at http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/superfish/superfish.js)

Also check if the permissions on the .js files are correct. Status report pages (admin/reports/status) may also be of help.